# How do I organize my YouTube videos to separate my Business and Personal stuff?

Tags: youtube

I'm uploading some software screencasts to YouTube. I've also got some other business related videos. But I also have a lot of personal stuff (family, hobbies, etc.).

I've read on this StackExchange that you can only have one Channel and it seems that when you create a new Channel (with a new Google Account) that it uses your name for the account.

How do folks organize this so that you can "present" a business-like view to folks looking at your YouTube videos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that playlists are your friend. You can create one playlist with business videos and another with private videos. If you want to present your business videos you can for example show them like this: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLC286668637A5EEF5&feature=mh_lolz on youtube

Answer (score -2):

For lack of a better tool, I use the first letters of the playlist, for example 'Football-Trainings', 'Football-Great skills', and so on.